# Alembik developement and source code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ffmpeg, imagemagick, wurfl

In my project i am using alembik media server heavily. However i am unable to find the source code of the tag on the alembik site. The repository they are giving is not sure whether stable or not. somebody have knowledge if the alembik developement has been closed, if closed, then where i can found one stable tag of the code and if there any alternative to alembik